# WKWebView: Use same delegate code (WKNavigationDelegate) in multiple view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an application with 5 navigation tabs, each one with a different View Controller that has a WKWebView inside it. I would like to somehow use the same delegate code to prevent copy and pasting in each one.

**How do I reuse the "decidePolicyFor" code in different View Controllers?**

```
class DashboardViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WebViewUtils.getWKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView.load(Constants.DASHBOARD)
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

        if navigationAction.request.url?.scheme == "tel" {
            UIApplication.shared.open(navigationAction.request.url!, options: convertToUIApplicationOpenExternalURLOptionsKeyDictionary([:]), completionHandler: nil)
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
        }
        else {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this by `dependency injection` like this:

```
class NavigationBehavior: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        if let url = navigationAction.request.url, url.scheme == "tel" {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
        } else {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }
    }
}

class DashboardViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

    lazy var webView: WKWebView = {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        return WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    }()

    let navigationDelegate: WKNavigationDelegate
    init(navigationDelegate: WKNavigationDelegate) {
        self.navigationDelegate = navigationDelegate
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func loadView() {
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = navigationDelegate
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView.load(Constants.DASHBOARD)
    }

}

let delegate = NavigationBehavior()
let vc1 = DashboardViewController(navigationDelegate: delegate)
let vc2 = ProfileViewController(navigationDelegate: delegate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the navigation delegate code in an object like this:

```
class MyWebViewNavigationDelegate: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        if navigationAction.request.url?.scheme == "tel" {
            UIApplication.shared.open(navigationAction.request.url!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
        } else {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }
    }
}
```

and then use instances of this object throughout the app:

```
class DashboardViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!
    let webViewNavigationDelegate = MyWebViewNavigationDelegate()

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WebViewUtils.getWKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = webViewNavigationDelegate
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView.load(Constants.DASHBOARD)
    }
}
```